# Laws I created that I must follow?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

I have created a set of laws I must follow to enforce self-discipline. One law is *I will not steal candy from children*. It sounds sort of weird to say "I broke my own law", and sounds sort of mathematical/unfitting to say "I broke my own rule".

Is there a more appropriate synonym for a *self-created law*? Furthermore, what would be an appropriate phrase to describe the set of laws I have created for self-discipline? *A Code of Conduct*? A *doctrine*?

The cooler the phrase the better, as it'll make the laws easier to follow.

Comment: That you had to specify *not to steal candy from children* as opposed to *not stealing* in general disturbs me . . . ;-)

Comment: Some people call the rules they set for themselves "resolutions," since they're things they are resolved to do; Might that fit your purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can describe this in multiple ways, which one is coolest is up to you:

**Core Code of Conduct**
**Core Principles**
**Personal By-laws**
**Way of Life**
**Strict Sense of Self-Discipline**
**Sense of Self**
[**Super-ego**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id,_ego_and_super-ego#Super-ego)

Comment: *Strict* sense of self-discipline sounds a bit too much. A sense of self-discipline, may it be good or more, would do the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

"Set of [principles](https://www.google.com/search?q=principle)" would fit nicely, no?

Principle (n) a rule or belief governing one's personal behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I failed to keep to my own standards.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to recommend the phrase [*personal manifesto*](http://www.artofmanliness.com/2012/02/13/how-and-why-to-write-your-own-personal-manifesto/), described thus in the article "How and Why to Write Your Own Personal Manifesto" from the website *The Art of Manliness*:

> The word manifesto traces its roots to the Latin *manifestum*, which means clear or conspicuous.  A manifesto is defined as **a declaration of one’s beliefs**, opinions, motives, and intentions.

But all sources I could find said a manifesto is a *written* declaration of personal values. (The linked article also uses *manifesto* to mean this.)

In searching for a more general word I found [*credo*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/credo), defined by Merriam Webster to be

> an idea or set of beliefs that guides the actions of a person or group

Because *manifesto* and *credo* are commonly recognized for their corporate (namely, political and religious) uses, it may be best to use modifiers like *personal* or *my* to suggest that these beliefs are ones you've made by yourself and for yourself.